# Hide files between multiple instances of same android activity

Tags: android

I need to launch multiple versions an activity from my activity but as they all have the user id of the launching activity they can all see each others data in the filesystem.  Is it possible to prevent this, is there anyway of starting an activity so that its data will be hidden from other instances with the same user id ?

Comment: I'm assuming all these activities are within the same application. But when you say "data" do you mean `SharedPreferences` or what?

Comment: Why hide them from each other if they are all YOUR application? If you just need distinct files, just simply save them with different names.

Comment: because the app holds a web view that runs 3rd party apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in built mechanism in android that will allow this.  We solved this problem by adding policing access from web app via phone gap plugin